# Creating a responsive drupal 7 slideshow

Tags: css, drupal, responsive-design, slideshow

I've found a bunch of articles about how to create slideshows in drupal, and many that discuss making a slideshow more responsive on SMALLER screens...but I'm having trouble finding how to make a slideshow (with css or some other drupal module) that is responsive on LARGER screens (ie. what happens when the screen is larger in width than my initial image...how can I stretch it and make it look ok?)

For example, my image is 1000px wide. However, I want the slideshow to be the full width of the page. Thus I want the image to stretch to take up the full width of the page irrespective of browser size. But I also don't want the image to look poor.

Is there a standard technique (or any technique) to make this happen?

Comment: That's front-end task. Drupal is there just to provide back-end data or to allow slideshow to be back-end manageable.

Comment: Have you looked for a module to do this? Maybe something like [Owl Carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this bx_slider module Normally bx-slider.js create responsive slider.